# Bibtex says that it cannot find my biblio RRD.bib file

Tags: biblatex, compilation-error

Hi when I try  to run my main.tex, Overleaf tells me that it cannot find my 'biblio RRD.bib' file.

It's weird because I never used 'biblio RRD.bib' in my main.tex or even as a name for a file. I always used biblio.bib.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand where my error could come from. If anyone could help it would be very nice.

Comment: use the menu to delete your cached aux file, if that does not work, show the error you get in the log file (not the summary in the Overleaf web view)

Comment: It's working thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the menu to delete your cached aux file, which appears to have been corrupted by errors in earlier drafts.